# Continents, Countries, States and Cities in multiple languages

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new in Elasticsearch and I do need to developer a feature that has an unique input form that searches many documents. I create one language per document, ex:

**continents-en, continents-pt-br, countries-en, countries-pt-br, cities-en, cities-pt-br**

Each document has specifics attributes (id, code, name, lat, long...), ex:

**continents-en**
1, SA, North America

**countries-en**
1, US, United States
2, BR, Brazil

**countries-pt-br**
1, US, Estados Unidos
2, BR, Brasil

**cities-en**
1, New York, Lat, Long...

**cities-pt-br**
1, Nova Iorque, Lat, Long...

First question: Is that the best way to do that?

So, i created this elasticsearch search:

> curl -XGET
>   'http://localhost:9000/countries-*,continents-*,cities-*/_search' -d '
>   {    "size": 20,
>          "query": {
>
> ```
>  "function_score": {
>    "query": {
>      "wildcard": { "name": "#{query}*" }
>    },
>    "functions": [
>      {
>        "filter": { "term": { "_type": "continent" }},
>        "weight": 10000
>      },
>      {
>        "filter": { "term": { "_type": "country" }},
>        "weight": 8000
>      },
>      {
>        "filter": { "term": { "_type": "city" }},
>        "weight": 6000
>      }
>    ]
>  }    } }'
> ```

The problem is when i type **"bra"** on the input form, i receive the result: **Brazil** and **Brasil**. The mainly language is Portuguese so if i have a Portuguese translation i'd like to ignore the English translation because the results has the same country id.

How can i do that?

Comment: please show us some sample document, how are your jsons are structured along with schema and mappings